# Implementing DateSlider from codeus.net

Tags: android, android-widget

When I tried to import the project it did not work. There were no project files found. What I did next was tried to build my own app and included the files mentioned here https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider but facing some xml errors as the app: not getting recognized. This DateSlider looks cool and if anyone has any idea of how do I implement would be awesome help. Thank You

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?

Comment: Barak, will be trying today and would let u know........Was not concentrating on this module, but by the looks of it, it shud work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used it, and it is slick, but I had to make changes (and I used it when I was first learning, so there might be an easier way, but I haven't had the desire to go back and re-visit it).

1) Copy all the files into your own package (contents of src, res and values to their respective folders).  Put all of the `src` files into your main package (without all the subdirectories from the zip file).

2) Edit all of the layout *and* source files to remove references to the old package/app name and replace it with your package.  Basically replace any occurence of `com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider` with `com.yourpackage.name`.

An example: 
`com.googlecode.android.widgets.DateSlider.SliderContainer` becomes `com.yourpackage.name.SliderContainer` and so on.

3) Examine the demo and set up dialog as you desire following examples in demo program.

Here it is in action:

[image]

Comment: Hello Barak, tried to do this but am getting the same errors...I dont exactly know what am I doing wrong here....

Comment: Are you sure you got all the package references changed?  It took me three tries to get them all when I did it. Not sure if I was clear enough in my answer... I didn't use the subpackages either. All the source files went directly into my main package.  And make sure you change the package name in all of the source files as well as the layout files...  I better add that to my answer as it appears I left it out.  If that doesn't work, add logcat output to your question and we can try and figure it out.

Comment: There is a compile error, so logcat cannot come into the picture...Well as u ve mentioned i will give it one more shot...

Comment: Hello Barak, it is working fine.....My package reference had been missed out in a part......thanks for the help